# In which header do we find GLUquadricObj

Tags: compiler-errors, glut

I am trying to build linux from scratch and I am building [glut](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php). I have generated makefiles with  `mkmkfiles.imake`. It runs make then I have the following error in lib/glut

```
glut_shapes.c:55:8: error: unknown type name 'GLUquadricObj'
   55 | static GLUquadricObj *quadObj;
```

I want to know where this object is defined and implemented so that I can resume compiling.
I have tried searching in /usr/include/GL but the headers in there dont have it

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to install [libglu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libglu1-mesa-dev) first